# How to get rid of 'return new Promise' and not to lose data?

Tags: promise, async-await

In this case, there is nothing easier to wait until the data is received, and then resolve the Promise:

```
// Using Promise resolve/reject
module.exports = () => {
   return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      let doc = await Document();
      doc.on('data', async (data) => {
         resolve(data);
      });
   })
}
```

But what do I do in this case?

```
// Using async/await
module.exports = async () => {
   let doc = await Document();
   doc.on('data', (data) => {
      // ???
   });
}
```

Comment: Nothing. Use the promise.

Comment: You can await an async operaration, e.g. a Promise. Why do you want to "get rid" the of Promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need the `new Promise`, you just should use it as the operand of an `await` inside the `async` function, [not using an `async` function as the executor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572):

```
module.exports = async () => {
    const doc = await Document();
    return new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
        doc.on('data', resolve);
    });
};
```

However, I would recommend to use `once` instead of `on` so that the event handler is removed after the first occurrence of the event - the promise can be resolve only once anyway. Also if you have node v11.13.0 or higher you can just use the [`events.once` method](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_events_once_emitter_name) so that you don't have to build the promise yourself - and it also handles error events correctly:

```
const { once } = require('events');

module.exports = async () => {
    const doc = await Document();
    return once(doc, 'data');
};
```